# Изменение audio файлов: воспроизведение задом наперед

Tags: android, аудио, java

Есть аудио файл на sdcard. Как изменить его так чтобы он воспроизводился задом наперед? Или объясните как записать с микрофона звук и воспроизвести задом наперед.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Минимальный алгоритм:

- преобразовываем в raw/pcm формат, что бы получить набор отсчетов. Формально - это массив целых чисел.
- разворачиваем массив. Это элементарно и пишется одним циклом.
- преобразовываем, если нужно, в другой формат
- сохраняем, воспроизводим.

Хотя, 1 и 3 пункт обычно не нужен.

[Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6959930/android-need-to-record-mic-input) есть код, как записать звук с микрофона. Результат складывается в массив short'ов (потому что такой формат задан с помощью `AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT`).

разворот массива - это просто

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length / 2; i++) {
   t = arr[i];
   arr[i] = arr[arr.length - i - 1];
   arr[arr.length - i - 1] = t;
}
```

Конечно, это можно (и нужно) оптимизировать - вынести вычисления длины массива за пределы цикла.

Comment: а сохранить как? и воспроизвести

Comment: там же, по ссылке есть пример использования класса AudioTrack, который может воспроизвести такой буфер.

А вот с "сохранить" не все так просто. Можно просто в pcm сохранить, для этого только заголовок прицепить нужно будет и сохранить буфер. Если в amr формате, то можно использовать класс AmrInputStream. Для других форматов нужно искать свои классы.